# RequireJS: How to return an anonymous function result from define method?

Tags: requirejs

This is my `define()`:

```js
define([], function() {

  var month = ['January', 'February', 'March',
    'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
    'August', 'September', 'October',
    'November', 'December'
  ];
  var mydate = "",
    mysec = "";

  // Code to prefix 0 for single digit date
  if (new Date().getDate() < 10) {
    mydate = "0" + new Date().getDate();
  } else {
    mydate = new Date().getDate();
  }

  // Code to prefix st, nd, rd, th before date
  if (mydate == 1 || mydate == 21 || mydate == 31) {
    mydate = mydate + "st";
  } else if (mydate == 2 || mydate == 22) {
    mydate = mydate + "nd";
  } else if (mydate == 3 || mydate == 23) {
    mydate = mydate + "rd";
  } else {
    mydate = mydate + "th";
  }

  return {
    mydate: mydate,
    mymonth: month[new Date().getMonth()],
    mysec: function() {
      if (new Date().getSeconds() < 10) {
        mysec = "0" + new Date().getSeconds();
      } else {
        mysec = new Date().getSeconds();
        alert(mysec);
      }
      return mysec;
    };
  }
});
```

And, the following code shows where I call this defined method return values:

```
define(["date"], function(date) {

  return {
    LoginValidate: function() {
      $("#resp").append(date.mysec);
    }
  }
});
```

**The Issue**: Whenever I call the property `mysec` of defined method, it is always giving the same seconds of time for the each load of page. If it gives 30 seconds, until and unless I load the page again, I am resulting with the 30 seconds only. How to get the latest time (seconds)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole module definition is only evaluated once, so the value of `mysec` is not going to change from call to call.
If you want to pop the current date every time you access this property, turn it into a function instead:

```js
return {
  mydate: function() {
    var mydate = new Date().getDate()
    if (mydate < 10) {
      mydate = "0" + mydate;
    } 

    // etc., other postprocessing

    return mydate;
  },
  // (...)
}
```

Then every time you need a fresh date, call this function to generate it for you:

```js
define(["date"], function(date) {
  return {
    LoginValidate: function() {
      $("#resp").append(date.mydate()); // notice function call
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. your answer solved my issue. but whenever i append the result `$("#resp").append('<p>'+date.mysec+'</p>');` it is returning the function itself. if add directly like this '$("#resp").append(date.mysec);' it is working fine. Tell me how can append this?

Comment: This is why I added the "notice function call" comment. Your second snippet works because [jQuery.append is overloaded to accept a function parameter](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function). The first one converts the function itself to a String instead of calling it. Change to `$("#resp").append('<p>'+date.mysec()+'</p>');` (notice the `()`).